# Sort and rename files using a 9 digit sequence number

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, file-rename

I want to rename multiple jpg files in a directory so they have 9 digit sequence number. I also want the files to be sorted by date from oldest to newest. I came up with this:

```
ls -tr | nl -v 100000000 | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.jpg"; done
```

this renames the files as I want them but the sequence numbers do not follow the date. I have also tried doing

```
ls -tr | cat -n .....
```

but that does not allow me to sepecify the starting sequence number. 
Any suggestions what's wrong with my syntax?
Any other ways of achieving my goal?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you say the sequence numbers do not follow the date? When you run `ls -tr` alone, does it give you the order you want? If you want to sort by creation time instead of last modification time, use `ls -trc` instead of `ls -tr`.

Comment: Beware of [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). While in a particular closed environment it might work for you, it's an unsafe habit and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: yes, `ls -tr` gives me the order I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of your filename contains a whitespace, you can use the following:

```
i=100000000
find -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0'  | \
sort -zk1nr | \
sed -z 's/^[^ ]* //' | \
xargs -0 -I % echo % | \
while read f; do 
   mv "$f" "$(printf "%09d" $i).jpg"
   let i++
done
```

Note that this doesn't use `ls` for parsing, but uses the null byte as field separator in the different commands, respectively set as `\0`, `-z`, `-0`.

The `find` command prints the file time together with the name. 
Then the file are `sort`ed and `sed` removes the timestamp. `xargs` is giving the filenames to the `mv` command through `read`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DIR="/tmp/images"
FILELIST=$(ls -tr ${DIR})
n=1
for file in ${FILELIST}; do
    printf -v digit "%09d" $n
    mv "$DIR/${file}" "$DIR/${digit}.jpg"
    n=$[n + 1]
done
```

Something like this? Then you can use n to sepecify the starting sequence number. However, if you have spaces in your file names this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

If using external tool is acceptable, you can use [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm):

```
rnm -ns '/i/.jpg' -si 100000000 -s/mt *.jpg
```

`-ns`: Name string (new name).
`/i/`: Index (A name string rule).
`-si`: Option that sets starting index.
`-s/mt`: Sort according to modification time.

If you want an arbitrary increment value:

```
rnm -ns '/i/.jpg' -si 100000000 -inc 45 -s/mt *.jpg
```

`-inc`: Specify an increment value.